# Problem with error Message on Customer Registration

Tags: magento2, error, knockoutjs, messages, registration

I have a Magento 2 problem with the registration form. The problem only occurs on my test/production servers (`jelastic setup, centos)`, not on my vagrant machine running an ubuntu server.

Problem is, if a user tries to register using an existing email address and submits the registration form, magento redirects back to the form (POST createPost/ -> create/), but does not load an error message. If the user reloads the same page (GET -> create/) the queued error messages appear. It seems that Magentos quirky javascript refuses to make the call to 
"/customer/section/load/?sections=&update_section_id=false&_=..."

if the request was sent by POST. Like already mentioned this only happens on the online servers. Not sure what I can do to fix this or even debug the whole thing.

---Edit---
So far I've figured out it has something to do with the cookie "private_content_version". Unfortunately it is pretty hard to find out where this cookie is set and why Magento is refusing to do so. If the cookie is there, the error messages appear.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento Version is 2.0.6